# Как правильно передать JSON из JSTL в Java Script?

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, jstl

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь из JSP передать JSON.

```html
    <c:set var="json_text">
        [{"TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:30:22", "COUNTER": "COUNT_ALL", "VALUE": 635 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:30:22", "COUNTER": "COUNT_BAD", "VALUE": 1 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:30:22", "COUNTER": "QUALITY", "VALUE": 99.84 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:31:22", "COUNTER": "COUNT_ALL", "VALUE": 642 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:31:22", "COUNTER": "COUNT_BAD", "VALUE": 1 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:31:22", "COUNTER": "QUALITY", "VALUE": 99.84 }]
        </c:set>
    
     <script type="text/javascript">
    var jsonString='<c:out value="${json_text}"/>';
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    </script>
```

Воспроизводится ошибка 
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2**

НО если взять и целиком скопировать содержимое 
напрямую в Java script, то все работает.

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jsonString='[{"TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:30:22", "COUNTER": "COUNT_ALL", "VALUE": 635 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:30:22", "COUNTER": "COUNT_BAD", "VALUE": 1 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:30:22", "COUNTER": "QUALITY", "VALUE": 99.84 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:31:22", "COUNTER": "COUNT_ALL", "VALUE": 642 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:31:22", "COUNTER": "COUNT_BAD", "VALUE": 1 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:31:22", "COUNTER": "QUALITY", "VALUE": 99.84 }]';
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    </script>
```

Подскажите в чем проблема.

p.s. сначала думал, что в var jsonString='';
передается просто строка ,
НО проверил таким образом

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var JSONFromJSTL='<c:out value="${json_text}"/>';
jsonResult.push("Вывод JSON="+JSONFromJSTL);
result_json.innerHTML = jsonResult.join('<br>');
  </script>
```

в

```js
<div id="result_json"></div>
```

передается такой результат

Вывод JSON=**[{"TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:30:22", "COUNTER": "COUNT_ALL", "VALUE": 635 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:30:22", "COUNTER": "COUNT_BAD", "VALUE": 1 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:30:22", "COUNTER": "QUALITY", "VALUE": 99.84 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:31:22", "COUNTER": "COUNT_ALL", "VALUE": 642 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:31:22", "COUNTER": "COUNT_BAD", "VALUE": 1 }, { "TIME_STAMP": "2016-07-25 02:31:22", "COUNTER": "QUALITY", "VALUE": 99.84 }]**

т.е. то что нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

все дело вы было в 
**var jsonObj = ${json_text};**

вот так результат был достигнут

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsonObj = ${json_text};
            var jsonResult = [];
            jsonResult.push("Вывод JSON="+'<c:out value="${json_text}"/>');
jsonResult.push("количество строк json="+jsonObj.length);
result_json.innerHTML = jsonResult.join('<br>');
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для формирования json в jsp можно воспользоваться библиотекой тегов http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net